GridGain Throughput bottleneck using key value API
I am using GridGain Ignite as an in-memory database to serve data, data is stored as <Integer, String> key-value format, and each request contains a list of keys, I use
cache.getAll(keys).values() to get the list of all values from ignite cluster.
The server configuration:

ignite version: GridGain Community 8.8.34
ignite cluster: 4 nodes, each with
14 cpu and 100 Gi
cache: replicated on each node, 50Gi for each replication
my server: ignite thick client, in total 10 pods,
each with 6 cpu and 10Gi memory.

The test configuration:

the size of keys per request is 700
the response body is 850kb
5000 users, 10 spwan rate.

I wish my application could support 50k RPS, however, for current configs it can only support 2k RPS, and the response time will increase as the RPS increase. (it is tested that for my server application, it can support >100k RPS if there's no interaction with ignite, so I think the bottle neck should be on ignite side). THe following is the test metrics using locust.

The cpu and memory usage on my server application and ignite cluster is less than 30%, I wonder if there's any task queue on ignite that will block the cache get operation.

Have  I got it correctly that you are reaching up to 2000 RPS, where each "read" is a retrieval of 700 keys? That actually means 1.4 millions RPS what is quite a lot.

Also, 850 kb per response with 2000 responses per second means 13 gigabit/sec and it could be a network limitation

thanks for replying, you are correct, the true RPS on ignite cluster is 2000 * 700 = 1.4 million RPS. I indeed guess there may be some network limitation. But I've also heard that gridgain ignite can support over 10 million RPS, that is why I wonder if there's other bottleneck that can be tuned for ignite itself.

Ignite (and GridGain) can absolutely get 10mm RPS. They do that by scaling horizontally. Unless you're hitting some other limit, doubling the number of nodes will roughly double your throughput. The low CPU utilisation suggests you are hitting some other limit.

yeah I think there should be some limitation that can be tuned other than simply horizontally scale, which is why I post this to see if anyone has some idea.

You can measure your network bandwidth. For example, 12 gbit is the limitation for a lot of AWS EC2 instance types

I would have to ask, why are you using a replicated cache? If you were using a partitioned cache then 1/4 of your keys would statistically reside on each host. With this distribution pattern each host (with its associated network interface) would return ~1/4 of your overall data set. With a replicated cache each host can return all requested keys and as a result the cluster does more network related work! Generally you want to use a replicated cache if your have a small table that is used in joins often. Partitioned caches are recommended for large tables such as this one! Hope that helps.

my use case is for read-intensive application, so it will get better performance with REPLICATED mode, you can refer to this https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning#replicated

Vincent, that would be very true if you were doing traditional key / value gets where traditional means getting 1 or 2 keys at most with a single call. You are reading 700 keys per request! So in your case the process time becomes bounded by the search and data return portions of the key / value get process.

Please do yourself a favor and execute a test of your 700 key / value get operations using a partitioned cache and I am confident that you will see some very nice performance improvements. This would be especially true if you precede your operation with some up work of making your single get operation be a multi get operation where you are executing a get operation with a subset of keys that you know reside on 1 single partition or at least 1 single host. Hope that helps.

Vincent, you are also not listening to the same document that you pointed me to where it says that replicated caches are for SMALL tables. 50 GB, while not huge is certainly not small either. Hope that helps!

thanks for replying! I will definately set up a test for partitioned mode (actually I used partitioned mode all the time before, but this time I will have controlled variable to compare these 2 modes).
But as I understand, replicated mode means each node will have the whole data set, and when my thick client call cache.getAll(), it can get the result from a single server node, while using partitioned mode it is possible to get the result from multiple nodes since not all data reside on the same node, this can have some network routing between server nodes

Chances are, even with a replicated cache, Ignite will request data from the primary partitions, which will be distributed across the cluster. This is a good observation, but I'm not convinced that it will make a big difference.

My core belief is that with a partitioned cache each node will hold 1/4 of the primary partitions for the overall data set. As such each node only has to scan 1/4 th of the total data set and each node will use its network interface to transmit its data. This introduces smaller scans and 4 network interfaces for data transmission. How much will this matter, I cannot say, but having a reduced data set size for each node and having 4 nodes participate should help. I do hope that you report back your findings so that all can benefit from whatever you might find! Thanks!

some updates:
I tested for both partitioned mode and replicated mode, for both 4 sevrer nodes (same config), partitioned mode is slightly better than replicated mode, both around 2k-2.5k RPS.
And I notice that no matter how I tune the ignite configurations (like thread pool size), the cpu usage is at most 4-5 cpu (even if I give more cpu for each server node and client node). Because of this, I feel like more number of server nodes can have larger performance gain compared to cache mode and backups number.
One of the work around is to "flatten" cluster, horizontally scale the nodes, but each node with less resource. However, this is kinda brute force, and I'm not sure if this cpu usage can be optimized for ignite.
